# how to block user in Linux /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

How do I block a user in `/etc/shadow`?

I´m trying not to use "usermod". I thought it would maybe work if I add an "!" in front of the password.

This what i´ve tryed. But no luck...

```
sed -i 's/^:/\!/2' /etc/shadow
```

Thanks

Comment: `sed -i [...] /etc/shadow` seems like asking for trouble. What's wrong with `usermod`?!

Comment: lets call it a "challenge" :-D

Comment: Define "no luck"? Did the `sed` not work? Did that change not lock the user out? Were there any errors in your system logs?

Comment: You should never edit `/etc/shadow`, you can screw your system access. Instead, use `usermod` as @Biffen suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling an account via `/etc/shadow` is explained in this [section of Linux Administration Made Easy](http://tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/disabling-user-accounts.html). Note that this may not disable the account if other authentication methods are configured.